# Help In Gnome Desktop

Tags: server, gnome, remote-desktop, 18.10, xrdp

I have installed Gnome desktop in my Ubuntu Server and am using Xrdp to use GUI but the problem is RDP connection is very laggy.

For Temporary solution, I changed color depth from 32 bit to 15 bit On My Windows RDP but still, I see some lags in connection

I think it is because RemoteFX is not enabled in Ubuntu Server side

Please Help Me

GNOME: 3.30.1
Ubuntu Version: 18.10

Comment: Why didn't you just install a regular distribution of Ubuntu if you wanted the Desktop environment?

Comment: @Tim regular distribution means?

Comment: desktop releases such as those listed here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours